# Make an animated GIF transparent in Flash CS 5?

Tags: flash

How can you make an animated GIF with a transparent background in [Adobe Flash CS5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Professional#Versions)?

I have make an animation in Flash CS5. And I want to export it to an animated GIF file. But I want this animation with a transparent background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

File>Publish Settings and on the 'Formats' tab, select 'GIF Image'

The 'GIF' tab will then become available. Select it.

Check the 'Animated' radio-button in 'Playback' and 'Transparent from the 'Transparent' drop-down.

Comment: is not working. My gif is than not animated and not transparent

Comment: is there code in your fla? is the animation all on the main timeline? do you have a background image, preventing it from being transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Flash CS 5.5 does produce a GIF animation with a transparent background if you 'export' your file as a GIF file. In the 'publish settings', be sure to define color as 'transparent', not as 'alpha'! It may be necessary to save the file after defining a new preference before using the export feature.

Important Note: in the 'publish settings' preference pane, be sure to turn off 'smoothing' when you are using a transparent background. If you leave this setting on the anti-aliasing feature will create an ugly fringe of color around curved objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual method for Flash CS 5.5: In publish settings, Click HTML wrapper, click window, select transparent window; click OK or Apply and close. Go back into publish settings and click ‘gif’ in formats and click publish. Result: animated GIF with a transparent background.

Comment: A HTML wrapper parameters are important only if you publish swf. In other cases they are not needed.